# If a person at rest has an average heart rate between 60 and 100 beats per minute, how manysamples should you plot to obtain 5 beats in the signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, sampling

If a person at rest has an average heart rate between 60 and 100 beats per minute, how many samples should you plot to obtain 5 beats in the signal?

Answer (score 3):

Say you're sampling the heart signal at rate $f_s$, so you have $f_s$ samples per second. You have between 1 and 1.67 beats per second. If you plot $f_s$ to $1.67f_s$ samples you'll get one beat, so you need to plot between $5f_s$ and $8.33f_s$ samples to get 5 beats.